# Can Visual Studio 2017 save all opened files continuously?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use Git Bash (CLI) for all Git related tasks. Git can of course only recognize changes in files if Visual Studio saved them, which it does not automatically. I am used from IDEA that I do not have to take care of this.

I often <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Git Bash after having changed multiple source files and then realize I  need to save first, so I go back to VS and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and switch to Git Bash again.

**How can I make Visual Studio 2017 save all opened files continuously?**

I looked through the options but did not find anything.
I also use Resharper, in case it can do this.

Comment: Maybe this is a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947955/c-sharp-visual-studio-add-in-detect-when-saving-document

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574292/how-can-i-autosave-my-visual-studio-2015-files-when-it-loses-focus